# Cannot use the Editor Location Provider on Unity .exe built (Mapbox)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gps, mapbox

I used the Mapbox *LocationBasedGame* Prefab on Unity. As for Default, the provided GPS location inside the Editor is a simulated track of a walk through Helsinki. However, when trying to build the Application into a .exe file the Location Provider stops using the simulated track and does not provide any location.

I have already tried to change the *_locationProvider* variable in the **InitializeMapWithLocationProvider.cs** file from "DefaultLocationProvider" to "EditorLocationProvider" but it didn't change anything

So what do I have to change to use the Editor Location Provider in my .exe build?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own GPS trace or see how the `EditorLocationProvider` is set up in the Astronaut Game Example scene where you can specify the lat lon on the AbstractMap script.